# File not found error when launching IE10 with WatiN 2.1 on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, watin

In Visual Studio 2012, I created a Microsoft Unit Test project and added WatiN 2.1 via Nuget.
When try to launch IE10 on Windows 8, I get file not found error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
file specified.

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var driver = new IE("http://google.com");
        driver.Close();
    }
}
```

Then, I realize the `Copy Local` for the following two dll are grayed out and set to `false` so I can't set it to `Copy if newer`.

```
Interop.SHDocVw.dll
Microsoft.mshtml.dll
```

I can manually copy them to the bin folder, but is there a problem with the Nuget package or my Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I change the `Embed Interop Types` to `False`, then `Copy Local` becomes enabled.